# Choose n unique elements from n lists

Tags: algorithm, backtracking

I have been thinking about a programing problem. If we have n lists, we want to output n **diffrent** elements (each one from a **different** list). I suspect this can be solved with some kind of a backtrack algorithm but I don't see how to correctly implement it.

Comment: Set up a bunch of pools of numbers you can pick from each list. Pick a number from the first list and eliminate it from each of the pools. If a pool is ever drained, go back to the previous state and try picking the next element. That's all there really is to it, if you need more info, Google implementations.

Comment: To be clear: you want to pick exactly one element from every list, such that no two elements are the same in the final list? What happens in event of failure, i.e. when it is possible to pick s unique element for one or more of the input lists?

Comment: Excactly one from each list so that two elements in the final list are not equal. In the case where there is no solution we output -1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though you could solve this with backtracking as suggested in a comment, a more efficient solution would be to use a max-flow algorithm.
Model it as a graph. A Source, a Sink a node for each distinct element and a node for each list.
You have the source connected to each distinct element. Each element connected to every list it is in. and the lists connected to a sink node. Each edge with capacity 1.
The maximum flow is the maximum number of distinct elements from distinct lists you can select.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure that this has no bugs and solves what is being asked; and I hope I have understood the question right this time :)

```
            //test
            int[][] arr = new int[][] {
            new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 6 },
            new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 5 },
            new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 4, 9 },
            new int[] { 1, 1, 3, 8, 1 },
            new int[] { 1, 2, 7, 1, 1 },
            new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 } };

            int[] res = getItems(arr).ToArray(); //6,5,4,3,2,1

        private static IEnumerable<T> getItems<T>(T[][] array)
        {
            int N = array.GetLength(0);
            item<T>[] items = new item<T>[N];

            HashSet<T> hs = new HashSet<T>();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                bool ok = false;
                T[] arr = array[i];
                for (int j = items[i].Index; j < arr.Length; j++)
                {
                    T val = arr[j];
                    if (hs.Add(val))
                    {
                        items[i] = new item<T>() { Val = val, Index = j };
                        ok = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!ok)
                {
                    item<T> item;
                    do
                    {
                        if (i == 0) throw new Exception("no solution");
                        items[i] = new item<T>();
                        item = items[--i];
                        item.Index++;
                        items[i] = item;
                    }
                    while (item.Index >= array[i].Length);
                    hs.Clear();
                    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                        hs.Add(array[j][items[j].Index]);
                    i--;
                }
            }
            return hs;
        }
        private struct item<T>
        {
            public T Val;
            public int Index;

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("Val:{0} Index:{1}", Val, Index);
            }
        }
```